# error while taking input in c programming

Tags: scanf

[programming//in this code i am able only to enter one
value through scan F() FUNCTION  although i have used loop up to 5 but when i enter first value program automatically ends whats wrong please answer???][1]
code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

  



  #include<conio.h>
    int main()
    {
    int arr[5];
    int j=0;
    if(j<5){
        printf("enter\n");
    scanf("%d",&arr[j]);
    printf("well enter next");
    int y;
    y=arr[j];
    if (y<5)
    { printf("value:%d",arr[j]);
    }
    j++;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: There's a lot wrong here. I suggest trying a smaller, simpler program.  Perhaps just print 5 times.  You can use a `for` loop or  a `while` loop.

Comment: i am begineer so could you give idea  whats wrong with the code plz??actually this program should take input from user in array . If the element of array is less than 5 it should be printed

Comment: I'll post an answer , but really it's just a way to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to figure this out on your own, but let me help you get started.

Let me show you how to store 5 integers taken from the keyboard and you'll have to learn the rest. C is a hard language to start with, so don't be discouraged, I'm still a beginner too.

I will also use some code formatting that I like. There are probably better formats out there but definitely think about how the code looks on the screen.

practice.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr[5];
    int j=0;
    
    printf("Enter the first integer:");
    
    while (j<5) {
       scanf("%d",&arr[j]); 
       printf("Next:");
       j++;    
    }

/* I'd then practice printing out the 5 integers.
*  Then you can figure out how to stop the loop based on some logical condition.
*/

return 0;
}
```

Compile with:

```
gcc -Wall -o practice practice.c
```

Comment: lot of thanks for this clarification brother .But i am still no getting exact answer to my question .what exactly wrong with the code. i tried this multiple time but could not find any error. if anyone have idea pl z share

Comment: You do not have a loop of any kind. That's a good starting place.